# Pasting text copied from email into contenteditable div adds line feeds

Tags: html, contenteditable

I have a question/issue with text being copy/pasted from an email into a contentediable DIV. I have searched Google, and certainly StackOverflow, but have not found any similar issues. (Perhaps I am not using the best search tokens to find a solution.)

I have a div which is contenteditable. Recently, I received some troublesome text that a user was unable to paste into the div. I copied it from my Thunderbird inbox. Here is the text:

> Lot Twelve A (12A), Section Thirty Two (32), STONEWALL VILLAGE, as shown in Deed of Subdivision, Dedication Vacation, Easement, Subordination and Partial Release recorded as Instrument Number 201708210099999 (Plat at Number 201708210099999), among the Land Records of Prince Georges County, Virginia.

When I paste this into my div, it looks fine on the page; but when I use the browser's Inspect Element, I see that line-feeds have been inserted into the text. This is a problem because my processing stores these line-feeds when I save the data.
[image: Snapshot of Developers' Tools showing linefeeds have been added]

These line feeds do not exist in my email inbox. To be sure, I even viewed the content in a Hex Editor and verified there are not CR's nor LF's in the text.

If I paste the text into sublime it looks normal; if I then copy/paste from Sublime to my div, all is just fine. Its only copying from my email to my div where I see the issue.

I have reproduced this issue in both Chrome and Firefox and even in jsFiddle.

HTML:

```
<div contenteditable="true" id="myDiv"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#myDiv {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  width: 500px;
}
```

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/x3x6vnxp/

Is there something about the PASTE functionality which behaves differently depending on where the COPY was performed? More importantly, how do I keep the browser from adding these new-lines? I cannot simply strip all line-feeds because it is possible a user might want to copy/paste text with legitimate line-feeds.

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: I think this could be a thunderbird problem. I tried your jsfiddle out on some of my emails from the iCloud app on my mac (HTML and plaintext!) and all of them worked fine.

Comment: Yes, I am having a hard time reproducing the issue outside of Thunderbird; but what I cannot figure out is why when I copy/paste from Thunderbird to a HexEditor, there are no carriage returns (x0d) nor linefeeds (x0a). (Note someone updated my quesiton so the text is now formatted as a blockquote with appropriate styling; this breaks things if you try to copy/paste the sample into my jsFiddle as all the formatting gets pasted as well)

Comment: [deleted comment]